# Can you use an open access CC-BY ND scientific article for text annotation?

Tags: open-access, license

We plan to use clinical trial articles in one of the text annotation projects. This article mentions the license below.

*This is an open-access article under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs License, which permits use and distribution in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited, the use is non-commercial, and no modifications or adaptations are made.*

I am not sure if we can use this article for text annotation and distribute the annotated text.

Answer (score 5):

Annotated versions are examples of derivative works. Distribution of annotated copies would thus not be automatically allowed under that license. You could contact the copyright holder and seek permission to distribute such derivative works.